# Fazer todo javascript ler o caracter utf-8 ou iso-8859-1

Tags: javascript

Tenho um arquivo `js`, no qual eu minifico para realizar as tarefas devidas. O que acontece que sempre que eu adiciono esse `js` em minhas páginas, onde ele é chamado, os caracteres da língua portuguesa ficam ilegíveis. Então creio que falta ou o `UTF-8` ou o `ISO-8859-1`. Mas a pergunta é, como eu coloco essas chamadas em um único lugar em meu arquivo `js`, de forma que qualquer função dentro do arquivo faça uso desses includes. Uma única leitura. Não gostaria que em cada método eu colocasse essa chamada, a menos que não tenha como. Exemplo abaixo, coloquei apenas uma parte do meu arquivo `js`, o início e parte de uma das funções existentes:

```
var tituloMultiBrowser;

(function () {
    window.showModalDialog = window.showModalDialog || function (url, arg, opt) {
        url = url || '';                                     //URL
        arg = arg || null;                                   //Argumentos
        opt = opt || 'dialogWidth:300px;dialogHeight:200px'; //Opções: dialogTop;dialogLeft;dialogWidth;dialogHeight/CSS styles

        //Função Chamadora
        var caller = showModalDialog.caller.toString();

        var doc;

        var i = 0;

        if (window.parent.name == 'JANELASIS') {
            doc = window.parent.document;
        }
        else {
            var janela = window.parent.name;
            var janelaPai = window.parent;
            while (janela != 'JANELASIS' && i <= 20) {
                janelaPai = janelaPai.parent;
                janela = janelaPai.parent.name;
                i++;
            }
            doc = janelaPai.parent.document;
        }
..............................
}
```

Comment: Porque não padroniza tudo pra UTF-8?

Comment: A questão não está em ser utf ou iso, mas onde. Já fiz, mas como o que eu fiz é a mesma coisa postada pelo Gabriel Rodrigues, resolvi marcar a resposta dele, pois ele me deu a mesma solução que eu havia encontrado. Obrigado.

Comment: Por isso falei sobre padronizar tudo para UTF-8, adiciona BOM nos arquivos que resolve. Em HTML5 até adicionaram uma regra onde o BOM sobrepõe qualquer declaração de caracter no corpo do documento. http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark.en.php

Comment: Só a título de curiosidade, o UTF-8 zoou tudo aqui. Só consegui com ISO-8859-1. Não sei, tecnicamente, o que cada um deles faz de diferente do outro, mas um deu certo e outro não.

Comment: ISO 8859 1 é ASCII extendido onde o ASCII normal usa só 7 bits, o extendido adiciona mais 1. Tem vários deles, o UTF8 que é uma das representações Unicode (existem outras, UTF16, UTF32...) suporta todas as linguagens existentes no planeta e até algumas falsas (Klingon). O tema é um pouco confuso no começo, esse artigo http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html ajuda bastante entender as diferenças.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

geralmente definimos na tag `meta` do site : `<meta charset="utf-8">` mas creio que você pode fazer algo do tipo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[path]/lang.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Existe ainda dois frames que não carrega de forma correta as páginas dentro dele, falando dos caracteres.

Comment: no começo da página que você chama o iframe esta com `charset="utf-8"` ?

Comment: utf-8 não está bacana, somente com 8859-1. Não sei porque, mas não deu certo utf-8.

Comment: você esta usando qual html ?

Comment: Cara, esse site começou a ser projetado no final dos anos 90 e início dos anos 2000. De lá para cá, teve diversas mãos e alterações. Tem de tudo aqui, menos html 5. Só para se ter uma idéia, agora que estão adequando ao uso do chrome(nossa missão aqui), pois até então rodava apenas no IE e versões bem antigas. É um desafio. Uma mescla de tudo, como: ASP, Asp.Net, Java. Um chamando o outro, isso é o que eu conheço. Aplicações desktop em Delphi para conversar com o site, é um mixtão.